# How Do I Send Data From One Computer To Another Without A Server (in C++)?

Tags: c++, networking, connection

so I want to send an int32 (or any 4 bytes data) from one pc to another, the size of the data will always be the same, I don't need any checking to see if both pcs are online or any disconnect function, if pc2 didn't receive the data or he went offline, I just want pc1 to send the data, if pc2 is offline nothing happens and if it's online it store it somewhere.
Most tutorials I've found uses a server way of connecting, so there are 3 pcs, 2 clients and 1 server, client1 sends data to the server and the server sends it to client2, but is there a way to send it directly to client2, as if client2 is the server?

Comment: From your tutorials, you might follow client to server steps.

Comment: You could use a simple POSIX socket with TCP or UDP protocol, but one side must always as as a "server" because it must listen for the incoming message.

Comment: google for a c++ network chat program

Comment: @Quimby actually you do not listen (in the sense of calling `listen()`) on an UDP socket.

Comment: @JakobStark yes, you are correct, perhaps I meant to say "expect to receive"? :)

Comment: @Quimby I also caught myself writing "listen" in my answer ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common protocols used to send raw data over an ip based network. They are called TCP and UDP and serve slightly different approaches.

- TCP is connection oriented and relies heavily on the server client model. On host acts as a server and accepts incoming requests on a predefined socekt. After the TCP connection is setup, you have a duplex (two-way) stream that you can use to exchange data.
- UDP is a packet oriented protocol. One host (usually called the server) listens to imcoming packets and can answer them. No real "connection" is established tough.

You probably want to use UDP. Note that altough this protocol does not establish a connecion, there still needs to be at least one host, that is waiting for incoming data on a predefined port. This one is usually called the "server". However also the client can bind its UDP socket to a specific port and thus can act as a "client" and a "server" during the same time.

You can setup both hosts to listen and send on/to the same preefined port number and achieve a connectionless packetoriented way to exchange data. That way both hosts act as server and client simultaneously.

How you actually implement this, depends on your operating system. On Linux (and other POSIX compatible OSes) you can use standard UDP sockets, on Windows there is some equivalent API. Either way I suggest you to first follow a tutorial on how to program a standard TCP server and client, as most of the operations on the sockets are similar (create the socket, bind it to an address:port, and read/write data from it).